# How to set an 'initial breakpoint' in Visual Studio 2005 automatically?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windbg, breakpoints

I would like VS to break as soon as it's entry point is hit (whatever it is).

In WinDBG, I know of a similar concept, the [initial breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Can I achieve the same effect in Visual Studio, generally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t547b0f3(v=vs.80).aspx

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click on the project
2. From the shortcut menu, choose Debug and click Step Into new instance.

You might need to set the project as "Startup project" or something like that, if your solution contains multiple projects.